# How to get the organization (tenant) id from user profile using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I'm creating an add-in that I to sell using organizational licenses.

I have implemented an authentication scheme on the add-in. I'm currently asking for `User.Read` scope for a sure authenticating using and Azure v2 endpoint. To get the user's information I'm querying

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

To properly test for the user's license I need extract the user's organization's identification. However, the user information I receive from the Grah request is increadibly lean. For an AAD account the schema looks something like:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  businessPhones: [],
  displayName: "FirstName LastName",
  givenName: "FirstName",
  id: "unique-id",
  jobTitle: null,
  mail: "First.LastName@COMPANYDOMAIN.COM",
  mobilePhone: null,
  officeLocation: null,
  preferredLanguage: null,
  surname: "LastName",
  userPrincipalName: "FILastName@COMPANYDOMAIN.COM"
}
```

If I use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/BETA/me
```

I get more information, but nothing that helps me pin down a unique id on the user's organization.

Is there a different scope I need to use to get information for the user's organization? And if there is not, can I rely on parsing the domain name from the user's email as a unique id for the user's organization? Do I need to query a different API?

#### Update: the OAuth response

In case it helps, after the user authenticates with AD, I receive the following response:

```
{
    access_token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFEWDhHQ2k2SnM2U0s4MlRzRDJQYjdyN1VLTzdJSDJSLWpTcmpScU9..."
    expires_at: Fri May 18 2018 07: 18: 42 GMT - 0400(Eastern Daylight Time) {}
    expires_in: "3599"
    provider: "Microsoft"
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"
    session_state: "012f4565-31bb-..."
    state: "259309..."
    token_type: "Bearer"
}
```

#### Update: The full AD response using `https://graph.microsoft.com/BETA/me`

```
{
    @odata.context: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users/$entity",
        accountEnabled: true,
        ageGroup: null,
        assignedLicenses: [],
        assignedPlans: [],
        businessPhones: [],
        city: null,
        companyName: null,
        consentProvidedForMinor: null,
        country: null,
        deletedDateTime: null,
        department: null,
        deviceKeys: [],
        displayName: "FirstName LastName",
        employeeId: null,
        givenName: "FirstName",
        id: "ebdcf715-43c5-4f48-ad0d-b798a3330849",
        imAddresses: [],
        jobTitle: null,
        legalAgeGroupClassification: null,
        mail: "FirstName.LastName@COMPANYDOMAIN.COM",
        mailNickname: "FirstName.LastName",
        mobilePhone: null,
        officeLocation: null,
        onPremisesDomainName: "COMPANYDOMAIN.COM",
        onPremisesExtensionAttributes: {
            …
        },
        onPremisesImmutableId: "...RVWAty...",
        onPremisesLastSyncDateTime: "2018-05-10T18:13:45Z",
        onPremisesProvisioningErrors: [],
        onPremisesSamAccountName: "FILastName",
        onPremisesSecurityIdentifier: "...-21-1412366426-...",
        onPremisesSyncEnabled: true,
        onPremisesUserPrincipalName: "FILastName@COMPANYDOMAIN.COM",
        passwordPolicies: "DisablePasswordExpiration",
        passwordProfile: null,
        postalCode: null,
        preferredDataLocation: null,
        preferredLanguage: null,
        provisionedPlans: [],
        proxyAddresses: [],
        refreshTokensValidFromDateTime: "2018-05-10T17:54:45Z",
        showInAddressList: null,
        state: null,
        streetAddress: null,
        surname: "LastName",
        usageLocation: "US",
        userPrincipalName: "FILastName@COMPANYDOMAIN.COM",
        userType: "Member"
}
```

#### Update: Decoding `access_token` with jwt.ms

```
{
  "typ": "",
  "nonce": "",
  "alg": "",
  "x5t": "",
  "kid": "iBjL1Rcqzhiy4fpxIxdZqohM2Yk"
}.{
  "aud": "",
  "iss": "",
  "iat": "",
  "nbf": "",
  "exp": "",
  "acr": "",
  "aio": "",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "",
  "appid": "",
  "appidacr": "",
  "family_name": "",
  "given_name": "",
  "ipaddr": "",
  "name": "",
  "oid": "",
  "onprem_sid": "",
  "platf": "",
  "puid": "",
  "scp": "",
  "sub": "",
  "tid": "",
  "unique_name": "",
  "upn": "",
  "uti": "",
  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]
```

Comment: After the user logs in, you should get an Id token. That contains the tenant Id.

Comment: @juunas do you mean the `access_token`? How do I extract the tenant id from it? Maybe you'd like to post a full answer with the details?

Comment: I mean the id_token, is it not available to you in this case?

Comment: @juunas I updated the answer with the OAuth payload. You can now see the schema for the full workflow. AD users do have a longer profile, but no `tenant_id`, that I can see

Comment: If you decode the access token at https://jwt.ms do you see user info there?

Comment: I updated with the decoded token. Perhaps, `"tid"` may be the thing we are looking for?

Comment: Alright, cool, well if nothing else works you can get the `tid` from the token. That is the orgamization id.

Comment: Really? Sweet! Much thanks for the education. If you write this up in an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as such. Also, any documentation to where I can reference all the token params?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If nothing else works, you can decode the access token and get the `tid` claim. That is the id for the Azure AD tenant.

You can find the documentation for the claims in tokens from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims

For example, here is what it says for `tid`:

> An immutable, non-reusable identifier that identifies the directory tenant that issued the token. You can use this value to access tenant-specific directory resources in a multi-tenant application. For example, you can use this value to identify the tenant in a call to the Graph API.

Answer (score 21):

This seems to work

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization
```

The id property is the Tenant Id

[Grahp Explorer link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=organization&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com&requestBody=eyJleHRlbnNpb25fZjhiMDRhYmYzOWQ0NGMxZDhiMWJlNDNkYzg2ZTNiMzVfcG9ydG9FbmRwb2ludHMiOiJ0ZXN0c2hhcmU6NDQ1LHRlc3RzaGFyZTI6NDQ1In0=)

Comment: well this worked, mind sharing the documentation for the request body you have used please?

Comment: It's a GET request. There is no body. Will update the answer

Answer (score 15):

Now this may not be using the graph API directly , but makes it extremely simple to obtain the tenant id of an organization. Just do a GET to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourdomainname}/.well-known/openid-configuration". The structure returned will have the tenant id. Try this url for example in your browser: https://login.microsoftonline.com/microsoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration.

Comment: Perfect for first asking for a domain, checking it and finally ask for admin grants. otherwise I would have to do two authentications for my daemon app (Also see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp )

Answer (score 0):

I used the URL @ben suggested

"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourdomainname}/.well-known/openid-configuration"

The tenant_id is not an actual field; you need to parse from one of the URLs. I used "issuer": "https://sts.windows.net/{yourTenantIdIsHere}/",

or "token_endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourTenantIdIsHere}/oauth2/token",

In Python you can parse like this

```
import json

# Sample JSON string
json_str = '{"issuer": "https://sts.windows.net/59ea4f14-dba2-4123-b73d-100c40a34608/"}'

# Parse the JSON string into a Python dictionary
data = json.loads(json_str)

# Extract the 'issuer' URL
issuer_url = data['issuer']

# Split the URL by '/' and filter out empty strings
parts = [part for part in issuer_url.split('/') if part]

# The tenant ID should be the last part of the URL
tenant_id = parts[-1]

print("Tenant ID:", tenant_id)
```