# How to create new Microsoft organization?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm completely new to ms world and trying to access API under my personal account

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

However this API says that it can only be accessed using `Delegated (work or school account)`.

Can anyone explain how to setup new organization account (taking into account that we have no organization yet), which ms service to use and which plan to subscribe for, if needed. They have so many services and it looks so confusing to assemble all this together, so please help.

Comment: see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory

Comment: do you mean I should buy azure subscription and this way my organization will be registered and then I can start inviting users to it?

Comment: Before this you need to have a tenant:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-access-create-new-tenant

Comment: You don’t have to buy an Azure subscription, I think you can also use a free account: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comments, first you need to [have a tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-access-create-new-tenant). If you have not buy an Azure subscription yet,  you can also use a [free account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/).

Then you can create a new [work account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory) or invite [guest users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/add-users-administrator)  in the tenant.

Comment: right, seems like azure registration did the trick,thanks